# Public ReadOnly Property from PreviousPage returns 'nothing'

Tags: vb.net, webforms, jsrender

I have a public readonly property BatchInvoice as String  which I read on the next page using PreviousPage. Other properties I have set is working fine. Just this one string which returns nothing.

Here is my code.

```
Private _sBatchInvoice As String

Public ReadOnly Property BatchInvoice As String
    Get
        Return _sBatchInvoice
    End Get
End Property

_sBatchInvoice is populated from an AsyncFileUploadEventArgs.

Protected Sub BatchUploader_UploadedComplete(sender As Object, e As AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs)
    Dim sArrayList As String()

    With class1
        If uplBatchFile.HasFile Then
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)

            Dim savePath As String = MapPath(IO.Path.Combine("~/Temp", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uplBatchFile.FileName)))
            uplBatchFile.SaveAs(savePath)
            sArrayList = .GetBatchUpload(uplBatchFile.FileName)
            Dim i As Integer

            For i = 0 To sArrayList.Length - 1
                _sBatchInvoice = _sBatchInvoice & "'" & sArrayList(i).ToString() & "',"
            Next

            'remove last comma
            _sBatchInvoice = _sBatchInvoice.TrimEnd(CChar(","))
        End If
    End With


End Sub
```

On the next page, I access BatchInvoice by:

```
Public sInvoiceList as String

With PreviousPage  
sInvoiceList = .BatchInvoice '-- this returns 'Nothing'  
End With
```

What could have i missed?

thanks in advance!
Joel

Comment: WebForms?  MVC?  add the appropriate tag to your question.

Comment: Where does PreviousPage come from?

Comment: Hi @Sam. It's sort of an MVCish approach. it's using webforms with JSRender.

Comment: Hi @Matt, the first part of the codes is from the previous page. When i access the property BatchInvoice from the previous page in the current page, it returns nothing. Hope i answered your question correctly.

Comment: What sort of Object is PreviousPage, where is it set? I suspect that your `_sBatchInvoice` variable is being cleared on a postback if you are using WebForms, but without more code its hard to guess

Comment: Yes, you are correct Matt. I am using a webform. Here is the scenario, on my Create.aspx.vb I have an asyncfileuploader which gets a batch template. once i get the file it reads through a column with a invoice numbers. I place it in an array and I want to pass it to a next page for duplicate checking as a comma delimited string. Yes, it does postback. here is my submit button.

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Language, global_next %>"
                CssClass="button" PostBackUrl="~/Requests/DupCheck.aspx" />

Comment: I have edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for this.

For any reason, the public readonly property I set on the previous page is being cleared after the AsyncFileUploader UploadedComplete event. I replaced the control and it is now working. Thank you!

Joel